# SharePoint Deleting Custom Library

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I made a MOSS 2007 custom document library.
Now I want to delete it, I cannot figure out how to do it, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Document Library, click the "Settings" dropdown, go to "Document library Settings" and "Delete this document library" will be the top option under "Permissions and Management".  note you must have the appropriate permissions to do this (I believe it's Designer or Admin only).